# How do I get the files from Directory in order in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, io, directory

I'm getting the files from the Directory in asp.net using c# languages:

```
string[] array=Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("Image"));
```

My Image folder has images like Image1.jpg, Image2.jpg, Image3.jpg........Image100.jpg.

My Issue is, I'm not getting the image files in order. How do I get the Image files in order say Image1 to Image100....

yea...I solved it myself..Here is the Solution:

```
var arr = (from u in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("Images")) let fi = new FileInfo(u) orderby fi.CreationTime select u);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ `OrderBy`:

```
string[] array = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("Image"))
                          .OrderBy(x => x)
                          .ToArray();
```

or without LINQ, using `Array.Sort` method:

```
string[] array = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("Image"));
Array.Sort(array);
```

But it will sort using default string comparison, so `Image100` will be before `Image2`.

It will be a bit more tricky to sort it using the number only, but you can do it with linq:

```
string[] array = (from f in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("Image"))
                  let n = int.Parse(f.Replace("Image", string.Empty).Replace(".jpg", string.Empty))
                  order by n
                  select f).ToArray();
```

Comment: sorry...not worked...When using Last option, I got an message that the input string was not in a correct format..

Answer (score 2):

Try like this;

```
var images = from img in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("Image"))    
             orderby img descending 
             select img;
```

Or as an alternative, you can use [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx);

```
var images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("Image"))
                      .OrderByDescending(img => img);
```

Comment: Actually.. the imagename (like Image1.jpg) is in a string format..so the orderby is not working properly...

Answer (score 1):

you can use linq like this:

```
Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("Image")).OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
 List<string> s = new List<string>();
 s.Add("image1.jpg");
 s.Add("image10.jpg");
 s.Add("image3.jpg");
 s.Add("image45.jpg");
 List<string> lst = s.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split('.')[0].Split(new string[] { "image" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1])).ToList();
```